# Axios requests with credentials resulting in Network Error in MacOS Safari or any iOS browser

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I'm trying to do an API request from a react client to a node server using Axios. The request works in MacOS Chrome browsers but does not work on MacOs Safari or iOs Safari and iOS Chrome.

In the same code I make other calls to the same API (different endpoints) and it works with no problems at all in safari and iOs.

I console.log the exception and I am given a very basic Network error with no detail:
[image: network error image]

My axios request looks like this:

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

return axios.get(API_ENDPOINT + '/api/auth/user_data/' + user_id + '/')
        .then((response) => {

            if (response.data.email) {

              localStorage.setItem('user_id', response.data.id);

              this.setState({
                user_id: response.data.id,
              });
              return true;
            } else {
              this.logout();
              return false;
            }
        }).catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
          this.logout();
          return false;
        });
```

My express server cors settings look like this:

```
const app = express();

var corsOptions = {
  credentials: true,
  origin: ["https://[production-domain.com]", "http://localhost:3000"]
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

If I hit the API from the browser directly I get a successful response:

[image: successful get request from browser]

The error occurs in both my localhost environment (client on localhost:3000 hitting server on localhost:9090) and my production environment (client on production-domain.com:5000 hitting server on production-domain.com:9090)

To me, this rules out problems with the webserver (nginx), which I only use in production.

From my server logs, I can tell that the request is reaching the server, because it triggers logs on my server-side function for the above endpoint. The error is in the response never being sent back to the react client.

My server-side response handler is:

```
    router.get('/user_data/:id', (req, res) => {

        console.log("User is authenticated on server: " + JSON.stringify(req.isAuthenticated()))

            if (!req.user) {
                // The user is not logged in, send back an empty object
                console.log("THE USER IS NOT LOGGED IN")
                res.json({});
            } else {
                console.log("The supplied user ID is: " + req.params.id);
                console.log("The stored user ID is: " + req.user.id);

                // Otherwise send back the user's email and id
                if(Number(req.params.id)===Number(req.user.id)){
                    console.log("USER " + req.user.id + " IS LOGGED IN")
                    res.json({
                        email: req.user.email,
                        first_name: req.user.first_name,
                        id: req.user.id,
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log("Client side user ID does not match. Logging out.")
                    req.logout();
                    res.json({});
                }
            }
    });
```

In my server logs I can see:

```
User is authenticated on server: true
The supplied user ID is: 35
The stored user ID is: 35
USER 35 IS LOGGED IN
```

I have tried changing the call from a GET to a POST, but it still does not work.

Very stuck on this, would appreciate any help.

Headers of the failed request are:

[image: headers of failure]

Headers of a successful call are:

[image: successful axios call]

Comment: "The error is in the response never being sent back to the react client." So wouldn't this mean your error is in your response handler on the server side? Post your response handler.

Comment: Added the response handler. It works fine on Chrome in my macbook, but not Safari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue turned out to be a race condition on the server response (I think).

My axios call was inside of a function in my react client that was being called by both a child class, and on component load, and resulted in my axios request to this endpoint being called twice. I'm not 100% sure why this would result in a response failure, but by making sure it was only called once resolved the issue.

Comment: still pretty odd that it was only happening in Safari! Glad it got sorted